# Data Overage in Old Salesforce Org

Tags: community, data-loader, salesforce-id

I have an old salesforce org that I have kept alive with one license remaining.  The org was previously used for an inventory system and has a lot of data storage taken up.  This has caused some red flags recently at salesforce and I have been contacted to either purge the data or I will be charged.  Can anyone help me get the data within means?  I only need the information that is on the account and contact and Opportunity pages. And also needs to export all data from salesforce org.

Please help me how can I export all records and delete the records.

[image: Storage Usage]

Comment: you can use Dataloader or SF dataloader app to take backup of your data. Also you can use export data from SF to take backup in csv and then in future restore them in your org.

Answer (score 0):

You can Export all or selective data using **Data Export** functionality. You can select Object for which you want to export the data.

This functionality takes some time. In my org it takes around 3 days for 16 GB of data.

It is available under Setup>Data Management>Data Export. You can click on export now.

If you need immediate export you may have to use data loader.

[image: Data Export Screenshot]

After exporting, you can delete some data so that you are within specified limits.

I see that your specified limit is 1 GB and there is a lot of data. It will be better if you can move this data to another inventory System which itself will be a huge task.

From the screen shot I am not able to see what objects are taking most space but if you able to see that then you will have to delete data from those objects.

Comment: In my org I have to export custom object records data and then after wants to delete all custom records. Can you suggest which tool is useful to delete all records ASAP.

Comment: For Objects such as Accounts, Leads contact etc, you can use Mass Delete option in Data management. For others you will have to use Data loader. You may contact sales-force support and see if they can purge your data.